# Formula for Derivative of Wronskian with Trace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant, trace, wronskian

> Let $W$ be the Wronski matrix of a fundamental system of the homogeneous linear differential equation system
> $$
> y^{(k)}+A_{k-1}(x) y^{(k-1)}+\ldots+A_1(x) y^{\prime}+A_0(x) y=0,
> $$
> where the $A_j$ are continuous functions on an interval with values in the space of $n \times n$-matrices. Then
> $$
> (\det W)^{\prime}+\operatorname{tr} A_{k-1} \det W=0 .
> $$

I was able to solve this problem. I leave it open for curious readers. A hint is the comment below this question.

Comment: You can write the first ODE as a system of first order ODEs